# JS Image change won't work under other tags (should be a simple fix)

Tags: javascript

Hey guys,
basically this is my page and the JS simply changes the images if one is clicked, this works grand if the  `<a href="#1" onclick="worseChange()"> <img src='worseun.png' name='worse' border='0' /> </a>` is first beneath the `<body>`, but doesn't work if there is another `<img src='' />` above it! I'm still learning js and this is a head wreck, can anyone suggest a fix? Heres it working with nothing above

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    function worseChange()
    {
    var theImga = document.getElementsByTagName('img')[0].src;

    var xa = theImga.split("/");
    var ta = xa.length-1;
    var ya = xa[ta];


    if(ya=='worseun.png')
    {
    document.images.worse.src='worse.png';
    document.images.cd.src='cdun.png';
    }
    }

    function cdChange()
    {
    var theImgb = document.getElementsByTagName('img')[1].src;

    var xb = theImgb.split("/");
    var tb = xb.length-1;
    var yb = xb[tb];


    if(yb=='cdun.png')
    {
    document.images.worse.src='worseun.png';
    document.images.cd.src='cd.png';
    }
    }

    </script>



    </head>
    <body>
    <a name=1>Uno</a>
    <a href="#1" onclick="worseChange()"> <img src='worseun.png' name='worse' border='0' /> </a><br />
    <a href="#2" onclick="cdChange()"> <img src='cd.png' name='cd' border='0' /> </a>
    <a name=2>Dos</a>
    <body>
```

Thanks guys,
James

Answer (score 3):

That first line:

```
var theImga = document.getElementsByTagName('img')[0].src;
```

means, "get the very first `<img>` tag in the document, and then fetch its 'src' attribute value." You can instead give the "real" image an "id" value, and use `document.getElementById('whatever')` to get it.

```
<a href="#1" onclick="worseChange()"> <img id='worse' src='worseun.png' name='worse' border='0' /> </a>
```

and then

```
var theImga = document.getElementById('worse').src;
```